# How many people still upgrading from XP to Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

Now that Windows 7 is out, how many people are still trying to upgrade from XP to Vista ? Is there any site out there with this data ? I have found many sites with data about Vista's market share, but nothing on upgrade patterns.

Answer (score 5):

My company is going from XP directly to Win 7.

Comment: We managed to do the XP to Vista upgrade, but unfortunately it doesn't look like we'll be doing 7.  Budget just can't take another huge upgrade hit like that so soon.

Comment: Win8 is already in the makings and we still have some users on xp.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Brian. Looks like your IT staff jumped the gun.

Comment: Windows 8 will be another disaster (like Vista). Windows is like Linux, every other major release is a test.

Comment: Still trying to phase out Windows 2000 usage here.

Comment: Yeah, came as a complete shock (and too late) to our workstation deployment team how bad Vista was.  That said, I have 2 Vista machines at home that are perfectly fine for what I want them to do that I don't see any need to spend the $$$ to upgrade to 7.

Comment: Please do not answer to such questions. Please read SU's FAQ since this question is not regarding an issue.

Comment: @r0ca - this answer was migrated with the question.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know about that.

Comment: @Steve: What's wrong with Win2K? :-) I like to run it inside VirtualBox since it has so little overhead and still runs tons of useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that lots of places will upgrade to Vista in the near future since the budget problem, not all companies have enough money to upgrade to windows 7 directly.

Especially lots of schools (primary & high) will upgrade to Windows Vista because they will get it for almost free...